# Decreasing distance between legend's items in R?

Tags: r, legend, choropleth

I'm trying to create correct `choropleth()` map in R using `GISTools` package. I use `choro.legend()` to display my legend. However I can't create either correct legend placement, AND/OR I don't understand the role of `fmt` parameter in my `choro.legend()` function. It seems to me that `fmt` can decrease the space between my legend colors and description.

[image]

I found [choro.legend help page](http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/cran/GISTools/man/choro.legend.html) that states `fmt`is **"C style format for values stated in above choropleth class limits"**.

So this should just work with my classes values, not by the distance between legend items itself?

OR what is the human understandable meaning of this?

How can I decrease the distance between my `choro.legend()`'s items?

```
choropleth(my.shp, nc.lI[,1], shading = income.shade)
choro.legend(-12919698, 5314317,income.shade,title='My title',cex=0.8, bty = "n", fmt = "%0.1f")
```

Comment: I did a little digging/experimenting on this. I found this on C-style string formatting commands: https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/r-project/lib/R/library/base/html/sprintf.html . But this doesn't seem to have any bearing on the distance between legend items. I do notice that in your code the title of the legend is 'My Title' but in your image there is not title on legend. Could there be an issue here? I doubt it but it's worth looking into.

Comment: On further inspection, using a value of "%20.1f" produces a really wide legend (like yours) and a value of "%0.1f" produces one with the legend items much closer together. But you use a value of "%0.1f" and your items are spaced far apart. The only other thing that I could think of is potential white space padding the front of your values, but I don't know why you would have this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fmt` has nothing to do with the spacing of legend items. For a detailed description of `fmt` please see [Use C-style String Formatting Commands](http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/base/html/sprintf.html). Simply paste the following code snippet in your `R` console to see the differences (pi ~ 3.14):

```
sprintf("%f", pi)
sprintf("%.3f", pi)
sprintf("%1.0f", pi)
sprintf("%5.1f", pi)
sprintf("%05.1f", pi)
sprintf("%+f", pi)
sprintf("% f", pi)
sprintf("%-10f", pi) # left justified
sprintf("%e", pi)
sprintf("%E", pi)
sprintf("%g", pi)
sprintf("%g",   1e6 * pi) # -> exponential
sprintf("%.9g", 1e6 * pi) # -> "fixed"
sprintf("%G", 1e-6 * pi)
```

`choro.legend()` calls `legend()` internally. To reduce the horizontal spacing between legend items you should change the `text.width` parameter of the `legend()` function. 
Unfortunately `choro.legend` doesn't provide a parameter to set `text.width` externally rather computes it internally. I added a `space_reduction` parameter to the `choro.legend` and slightly modified the original function as follows:

```
choro.legend <- function (px, py, sh, under = "under", over = "over", between = "to", 
          fmt = "%g", cex = 1, space_reduction = 0, ...) 
{
  x = sh$breaks
  lx = length(x)
  if (lx < 3) 
    stop("break vector too short")
  res = character(lx + 1)
  res[1] = paste(under, sprintf(fmt, x[1]))
  for (i in 1:(lx - 1)) res[i + 1] <- paste(sprintf(fmt, x[i]), 
                                            between, sprintf(fmt, x[i + 1]))
  res[lx + 1] <- paste(over, sprintf(fmt, x[lx]))
  maxwidth <- max(strwidth(res)) - space_reduction
  temp <- legend(x = px, y = py, legend = rep(" ", length(res)), 
                 fill = sh$cols, text.width = maxwidth, cex = cex, ...)
  text(temp$rect$left + temp$rect$w, temp$text$y, res, pos = 2, 
       cex = cex)
}
```

Save this snippet in a R script file and `source` it. A reproducible code snippet would be like the following:

```
library(GISTools)

data(newhaven)
blocks

val <- blocks@data$POP1990
shade <- auto.shading(val)
choropleth(blocks, v= val, shade)
choro.legend(514000, 175000,shade,title='My Legend',cex=.8, bty = "n", fmt = "%0.0f",
             space_reduction=4000)
```

Gradually diminish/increase the `space_reduction` parameter to achieve the desired result.

[image]

Comment: Tried to use the choro.legend function as outlined above, but regardless of the value I set for space_reduction, I get the following error message: Error in legend(x = px, y = py, legend = rep(" ", length(res)), fill = sh$cols, : 'text.width' must be numeric, >= 0 My function call looks like: choro.legend(-85.80,45.3,tneffort.shades,title='Trapnet lifts per year', cex=0.6,bty="n",fmt = "%0.0f",space_reduction=4000) Can anyone identify the source of the problem?