# Decreasing distance between legend's items in R-- round 2

Tags: r

In response to the question posted [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189882/decreasing-distance-between-legends-items-in-r/256095#256095), Farid Cher provided a slick modification to choro.legend that enabled R users to control the amount of space inserted between legend colors and their description.  I am trying to use Farid's modification to choro.legend, but regardless of the value I set for the space_reduction attribute, I get the following error message:

```
Error in legend(x = px, y = py, legend = rep(" ", length(res)), fill = sh$cols, : 'text.width' must be numeric, >= 0
```

My function call looks like:

```
choro.legend(-85.80, 45.3, tneffort.shades, title='Trapnet lifts per year',  cex=0.6, bty="n", fmt = "%0.0f", space_reduction=4000)
```

Can anyone identify the source of the problem? Apologies to the community for initially posting this question as a comment to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I tried and got "unused argument (space_reduction = 4000). Try without this argument, removing it returned results for me.

well.. I used this choro.legend(514000, 175000,shade,title='My Legend',cex=.8, bty = "n", fmt = "%0.0f") which is a different coord system than your example. Maybe your "-85.80" has something to do with it.

Comment: I also was wondering if the coordinate system was the issue, but still am not sure what the fix would be...

Comment: I tried the negative value and it doesn't return any errors but still grumbled about the space_reduction. Have you tried removing space_reduction?

Comment: After that the next thing I would try is another coordinate system. UTM is a good start.